# How to get the integer value from the json object of google distance matrix in php

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get the integer value from the json object that is constructed from google distance matrix, but the value is being showed as int(). I tried typecasting ,json_decode and string operations on it, but it is still returning the same. Please help me with getting the actual value.

Please find below the code, actual output and expected output.

### php code:

```
<?php
$details = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=30326&destinations=30303&mode=driving&sensor=false";

$json = file_get_contents($details);
$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$kms =  var_dump($details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value']);
```

Actual output:
int(14459)

Expected output:
14459

Comment: you're doing var_dump. that's for debug output, and gives you type+value. you're getting EXACTLY what you asked for: an integer with value 14459.

Comment: $kms =  $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var-dump) outputs the information about a variable, including the type. See here for more info http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php.

If you want `$kms` to contain the value of `14459` then change the last line to

```
$kms =  $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
```

Otherwise if you want to print just 14459 to the screen then use `echo` instead of [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var-dump)

```
echo $details['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value'];
```